# Integrating fabric to existing project — how to resolve "No Android modules detected"?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

Simply trying to add [fabric](http://fabric.io) to existing Android project. Followed their instrustions for IntelliJ IDEA:

1. Registered
2. Downloaded and installed fabric plug-in
3. Logged in
4. Going to add android module, got this result

[image: No android modules detected fabric intellij idea android studio]

As you can see, actually there is android module at the project. How to fix this?

Comment: Did you get it fixed?

Comment: @MarcinLagowski See answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was forced to install Android Studio and integrate the plugin there to resolve this. Later found [guide for manual installation](https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/integration.html), which may be helpful.

Comment: Ok, but after integration you moved back to intellij?

Comment: I have the same issue and this answer doesn't resolve it

Comment: i have installed intellij ,should i install studio to work ?